# Why isn't the shop document being updated with a new balance? Node + Mongoose Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The code below attempts to set the shop **.balance** property to 10. When the route is called all functions run properly and no errors occur.

However, after the function is run and the shop that was just updated is looked at. It's **.balance** property is still 0? Why is this? Does it work when I update something with this syntax everywhere else?

Below is the code.

```
app.get("/:id/deductBalance/:amount", async function(req, res){

    const id = req.params.id
    const amount = req.params.amount

    let updatedShop = {}
    let shop = await Shop.findById(id)
    let currentBal = shop.balance
    console.log(currentBal)

    updatedShop.balance = 10;

    Shop.updateOne({id: id}, updatedShop, async function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log('changed shop bal')
        }
    })

    return res.redirect("/"+id+"/restockItems/option")
})
```

Below is the mongoose schema for shop

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var shopSchema = new Schema ({
    name: String,
    categories: Array,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    img: String,
    itemCategories: Array,
    manufacturers: Array,
    status: String,
    balance: Number
});


let Shop = module.exports = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

**UPDATE:** Turns out in the `Shop.updateOne({id: id}` part, `id` needs to be `_id` as the id's in mongo have an _ in front of them. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: it's still 0 in your db or just in the view after `return res.redirect("/"+id+"/restockItems/option")`

Comment: It's in both the db and the view. Since the view loads from the db.